# checking if textbox contains a word not working

Tags: c#, list, foreach, textbox, contains

It only seems to detect/check the first word in the list.

```
private bool ContentCheck()
    {
        List<string> FilteredWords = new List<string>()
        {
            "duck",
            "donkey",
            "horse",
            "goat",
            "dog",
            "cat",                  //list of censored words
            "lion",
            "tiger",
            "bear",
            "crocodile",
            "eel",
        };
        foreach (var e in FilteredWords)
        {
            if (memoEdit1.Text.Contains(e))
            {
                return true; 
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

 private void button_click (object sender, EventArgs e)

  {

   if (ContentCheck() == false)
   {
                    //do something
   }

   else if (ContentCheck() == true)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Error: Offensive word.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both situations in the `if` statement inside of your `foreach` block results in a `return`. Think about that for a second, the program will iterate the first item in the list, if it's a swearword it will return, if not it will *also return*. Both of those will exit the code and so the next item will never be iterated.

To fix this you need to change

```
foreach (var e in FilteredWords)
{
    if (memoEdit1.Text.Contains(e))
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return false;
```

to

```
foreach (var e in FilteredWords)
{
    if (memoEdit1.Text.Contains(e))
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Oh lol thanks, this was my 1st time working with bools lol.